# Order item entity/field definitions

Tags: commerce

On my Status Report (Drupal 9.4.8), I see the following error.

> Mismatched entity and/or field definitions
> The following changes were detected in the entity type and field definitions.
>
> #### Order item
>
> - The ID field needs to be installed
> - The UUID field needs to be installed
> - The Order item type field needs to be installed
> - The Order field needs to be installed
> - The Purchased entity field needs to be installed
> - The Title field needs to be installed
> - The Quantity field needs to be installed
> - The Unit price field needs to be installed
> - The Overridden unit price field needs to be installed
> - The Total price field needs to be installed
> - The Adjustments field needs to be installed
> - The Uses legacy adjustments field needs to be installed
> - The Data field needs to be installed
> - The Locked field needs to be installed
> - The Created field needs to be installed
> - The Changed field needs to be installed
>
> #### URL alias
>
> - The URL alias entity type needs to be installed

All the commerce functions on my site are working though, so I'm not sure these actually do need to be installed. I've seen a lot of suggestions about installing Devel Entity Updates, but when I tried running `drush entup` with that, I got these error messages.

> Exception thrown while performing a schema update. Cannot add unique key 'commerce_order_item_field__uuid__value' to table 'commerce_order_item': unique key already exists.

> Cannot add unique key 'commerce_order_item_field__uuid__value' to table 'commerce_order_item': unique key already exists.

Another problem is this message has been here for quite some time, so I can't offer anything helpful like a recent module I installed or other change. I'm currently trying to dig into core to see if I can find where/why it thinks these fields need installed.

Anyone experienced anything like this before and/or have any insight for me?

Comment: You can use the Devel Entity Updates module to fix this. But make sure to take a DB backup first.

Comment: @Jaypan, as mentioned above, I have tried that.